# difference in performance: virtualbox os and local os

Tags: performance, virtual-machine, operating-systems

Is there a specific difference in performance between an OS installed on a Virtual Box and an OS installed locally on a computer?

Is there any formula so that I could know what is lost when you install an OS in a virtual box.

For example, if you assigned 512Mb of memory in a virtual box os. But it is actually 256Mb when compared to its performance when it is installed locally.

Please, I need the information because we're making a comparative analysis on operating systems. And I can't just install Sabayon Linux, it might ruin the 3 other os that I have already installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the number of variables involved (everything from caching efficiency to what programs are running your host OS) it is practically impossible to know the exact difference theoretically.  However, I would do the following to determine this experimentally without affecting my current install;

### Overview:

1. Purchase an **identical** harddrive
   to what you currently have installed
   in your computer.
2. Remove the current harddrive you have so you don't mess up any of
   your currently installed stuff.
3. Install the OS's that you are analyzing to that harddrive -- note,
   they MUST not be installed in
   different partitions and the drive
   should be zero'd between changing
   the operating systems (this more
   closely simulates how it might look
   under virtual box -- i.e. a fresh
   drive).
4. Perform your benchmarking for each OS
5. Put your old harddrive back in
6. Fire up VirtualBox and install each OS, perform your benchmarking
   for each OS.

### Caveats:

- If you are trying to do a high-quality comparative analysis,
  you HAVE to do the comparison from
  each individual OS ON the hardware.
- Make sure you pick a good set of benchmarking software that doesn't
  bias toward one thing or another to
  heavily. And if you do bias toward
  something heavily (RAM usage
  perhaps?) make sure you get enough
  samples that the aggregate data is
  meaningful.
- Ensure the software running on your host os is the same AND minimal
  during your benchmarking process for
  each OS you sample
- I would recommend defragging your harddrive between installs of the
  OS's under virtualbox, this will help
  ensure the virtual disk will be more
  contiguous on disk

Answer (score -1):

There is, actually, a specific difference.

**In a virtual machine, the hardware that the OS thinks it's running on is *not real*.**

Whereas in a local, bare-metal OS, the hardware that the OS thinks it's running is, by and large, actually physically present.

Comment: ahh, this is not very accurate. CPU, RAM, hard disk is all very REAL, network controllers, graphics and sound are emulated.

Comment: hard disk is definitely *not* real, actually; while some VMs can present raw disk access to their guest OS, running a guest on a virtual HDD (eg /my/VMs/foo.vdi) is very common.

Comment: while a container is used, the action certainly happens for real on your HDD and if your disk is noisy enough might be able to hear it actually :P

Comment: one could say the same about any emulation -- even though the graphics is emulated, the VM desktop still shows up on my monitor; even though the sound is emulated, the VM media player still plays thru my speakers.  doesn't change the fact that my guest OS thinks it has a VBOX HDD and is displaying to an "Innotek ...VirtualBox Graphics Adapter".

Comment: @brice - i'm sorry, my comment was not using "emulation" in the technical sense described by those documents, and you're right, by that definition VirtualBox is not an emulator.  i was referring to the fact that the guest OS sees virtual hardware instead of real hardware *in most places*.  yes, the CPU runs the guest OS code natively (though even CPU features available to the guest can be restricted, eg number of cores).  on my testbed VirtualBox guest, the CPU (and possibly RAM, not sure) is *the only real hardware the guest knows about* -- everything else is virtual/emulated/fake.

Comment: (actually, i blame Molly for that; her first comment introduced the term "emulated".)

Comment: It's clear that this leaves room for a very interesting question on VHD performance!